# How quickly can I withdraw funds from my bank account after being granted a UK visit visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

3 days after applying, I received my UK standard visitor Visa a few days ago. 
Now I need those funds I showed, to book my flight tickets and other stuff.

How quickly can I withdraw funds from my bank account after being granted a UK visit visa? Can I withdraw the amount full or should I leave some? Do they still check my account even after being granted visa and/or at the time of arrival in LHR-Heathrow airport?

Comment: I think this is why credit cards were invented

Comment: @Strawberry It isn't, and recommending someone use credit when they don't need to is quite irresponsible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the opposite is true. No one should a credit card *except* when they don't need to.

Comment: @Strawberry I am unable to rightly apprehend the confusion of ideas that could lead to such a statement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I use a credit card all the time. At the end of each month I get one nice statement of everything I've bought that month, write them one check, and it is done. Plus I get the float on that month's worth of purchases. Plus the credit card offers various protections on the purchases, as well as points for traveling with later. You are right, I don't _need_ to use it, but it offers many advantages for those who pay off their balance in full every month.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not saying using a credit card in this manner is a bad way to go about your business - it isn't - but specifically recommending it for reasons other than that doesn't seem right. Certainly the notion that you shouldn't use credit when you _do_ need to is baffling to me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  The biggest advantage of a credit card (prior to ECB getting an Italian president, and interest going to zero) has always been _not_ buying stuff you can't afford, but buying stuff you _can_ afford _and_ getting interest for the money on your bank account while the loan on the credit card is 100% free during the approx. 6 weeks it takes them to charge in. Used to make everything you purchase 5-6% cheaper, effectively. That, and you need not carry a few thousand around everywhere you go just in case you see something you want to have.

Comment: @Damon But how does that help Beepin with their visa?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not in any way, but the advice not to use a credit card doesn't help either. :) I don't quite get the point of the question anyway, if you have a valid visa you can obviously enter the country (and visit the bank), so you can withdraw your money without problems. You usually can do that _without_ being physically present too, unless you insist on getting cash. So, not sure what the problem is. Only issue may be if you want more than 25-30k in cash you'll have to tell them a day or two in advance since they are usually unhappy with giving out such sums unexpectedly.

Comment: @Damon I didn't see anybody give advice not to use a credit card! :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is your money, use it as you please and when you please. The assessment is complete and the decision has been made, no one is actively looking at your bank statement anymore.

Except the IO who will interview you once you land, you may be asked for a proof of funds for your trip at that point. And if by then you are no longer in possession of enough funds for your trip, you may be denied entry.

Obviously it is normal and actually expected that by the time you reach the UK, you would have spent some of your money on tickets and other arrangements for your trip, so no one will hold you to the exact same amount you presented on the application stage.

Comment: Yes, you should leave pretty much all of it except what you need for airfare and the like.  Sometimes people borrow money simply to make a good showing to UKVI, our term that on SE is "funds parking", and naturally want to pay it back as quickly as possible... not such a good place to be.

Comment: yeah, or hide the fact that they're unemployed, travel months later, and now their bank account is all but empty.